# Recover email list from a mailbox using Python

Tags: python, flask, flask-mail

Is there any possibility or any library to log in to a given mail and recover a list of messages for a given sender? 
I mean the situation in which I provide an e-mail address, based on this address, all messages in the inbox are filtered, and I am returned to the list of e-mails or the user's last message. 
I use flask-mail to send emails, but I don't think it is possible to recover the list of messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the standard [mailbox](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mailbox.html) library. It provides functionalities to read mailboxes stored on disk using the most popular mailbox file formats (Maildir, mbox, MH, Babyl, and MMDF at the time of this writing).

Be warned, nowaday, for performance, reasons many mail clients are using embedded database engines to store emails. SQLite being popular choice, you can also try the [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) library.

Finally, You will also find exotic file formats like [Mork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mork_(file_format)). For that, you will have to write your own parser or turn to PyPy to search if someone has already done the work for you.

<sub>As a personal note, if your email client allows changing its storage backend, you may consider switching to a well know text-based storage format for your emails--it definitely helps in case of disaster recovery</sub>

---

As an example, I am using Thunderbird and set it up to use the *mbox* file format. So I can iterate over the message of my Junk folder that way:

```
>>> path = '~/.thunderbird/4tuag540.default/ImapMail/ssl0.ovh-1.net/INBOX.sbd/Junk'
>>> from mailbox import mbox
>>> junk = mbox(path)
>>> for message in junk:
...    # Prinf the "From" header:
...    print(message['From'])
...
```